# Initialization of very big vector in C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays

I created very big O(10M) floating point list in python. I would like to use this lookup table in my C++ project. What is the easiest and the most efficient way to transfer this array from python to C++.

My first idea was to generate c++ function, which is responsible for  initializations of such long vector and then compile it. 
The python code looks like above:

```
def generate_initLookupTable_function():
    numbers_per_row = 100
    function_body = """
#include "PatBBDTSeedClassifier.h"

std::vector<double> PatBBDTSeedClassifier::initLookupTable()
{
   std::vector<double> indicesVector ={
    """
    row_nb = 1
    for bin_value in classifier._lookup_table[:,0]:
        function_body += "\t" + str(bin_value) +" , "
        if (row_nb % numbers_per_row) == 0:
            function_body += "\n"
        row_nb += 1

    function_body += """\n };
return indicesVector;
}
    """
    return function_body
```

The output file has size of 500 MB. And there is not possible to compile it (compilation terminated due to gcc crash):

```
../src/PatBBDTSeedClassifier_lookupTable.cpp
lcg-g++-4.9.3: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

0x409edc execute
../../gcc-4.9.3/gcc/gcc.c:2854
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
```

The another idea is to store python array into binary file and then read it in C++. But this is  tricky. I cannot properly read it.
I generate the table using such simple command:

```
file = open("models/BBDT_lookuptable.dat", 'wb')
table = numpy.array(classifier._lookup_table[:,0])
table.tofile(file)
file.close()
```

Can you tell me how can I do it? I googled SO and I could't find andy sufficient answer.

Do you have any idea how can I deal with such big arrays.

I should have give you more detailed description of the problem. 
I use python to train the ML (sklearn) classifier and then I would like to deploy it in C++. Doe to timing issue (execution speed is a crucial part of my study) I use idea of [bonsai boosted decision trees](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6861). In this approach you transfer BDT into lookup table.

Comment: Do you have another process that needs to use the data from the Python process? Or is the C++ "program" supposed to be a module used from Python? Can you please elaborate on the underlying problem you are attempting to solve by "transferring" the data?

Comment: Can you reveal some part of produced C++ code for better understanding the problem?

Comment: "The another idea is to store python array into binary file and then read it in C++. But this is tricky. I cannot properly read it.". Unfortunately, that's the only sound option you have :) Wait, no: you could generate asm instead of C and link the asm code to your C code.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you want to put it in a large, compressed binary file? There must be some good reason since it will save you the trouble as well as probably load faster (try [Zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/wiki)).

Comment: The issue is I don't know how to grab the table from such file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNU tools it is rather easy to directly use `objcopy` to achieve that which is suggested by Jean-Francois; combining with python script of PM2Ring which writes a binary array, you can execute:

```
objcopy -I binary test.data -B i386:x86-64 -O elf64-x86-64 testdata.o
```

(depending on your actual processor architecture, you might need to adjust). The command will create a new object named `testdata.o` with the following symbols:

```
0000000000000100 D _binary_test_data_end
0000000000000100 A _binary_test_data_size
0000000000000000 D _binary_test_data_start
```

All these symbols will be visible as symbols with C linkage in the linked program. The `size` is not usable as such (it will be converted to an address as well), but the `*start` and `*end` can be used. Here is a minimal C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" double _binary_test_data_start[];
extern "C" double _binary_test_data_end[0];

int main(void) {
    double *d = _binary_test_data_start;
    const double *end = _binary_test_data_end;

    std::cout << (end - d) << " doubles in total" << std::endl;
    while (d < end) {
        std::cout << *d++ << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The `_binary_test_data_end` will actually be just past the last element in the array `_binary_test_data_start`.

Compile + link this program with `g++ test.cc testdata.o -o program` (using the testdata.o from objcopy above).

Output (`cout` by default seems to truncate the decimals awkwardly):

```
% ./a.out 
32 doubles in total
0
0.0625
0.125
0.1875
0.25
0.3125
0.375
0.4375
0.5
0.5625
0.625
0.6875
0.75
0.8125
0.875
0.9375
1
1.0625
1.125
1.1875
1.25
1.3125
1.375
1.4375
1.5
1.5625
1.625
1.6875
1.75
1.8125
1.875
1.9375
```

---

You can also assign these values into a vector very easily; `std::vector<double>` accepts 2 iterators, where first points to the first element, and second to just one after; you can use the arrays here as they decay into pointers, and pointers can be used as iterators:

```
std::vector<double> vec(_binary_test_data_start, _binary_test_data_end);
```

However, for big arrays, this is just needless copying. Also, using just the C array has the added benefit that it is *lazily loaded*; ELF executables are not read into memory, but they're paged in as needed; the binary array is loaded from file into RAM only as it is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of how to write Python float data to a binary file, and how to read that data in C. To encode the data, we use the `struct` module.

### savefloat.py

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from struct import pack

# The float data to save
table = [i / 16.0 for i in range(32)]

# Dump the table to stdout
for i, v in enumerate(table):
    print('%d: %f' % (i, v))

# Save the data to a binary file
fname = 'test.data'
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    for u in table:
        # Pack doubles as little-endian 
        f.write(pack(b'<d', u))
```

**output**

```
0: 0.000000
1: 0.062500
2: 0.125000
3: 0.187500
4: 0.250000
5: 0.312500
6: 0.375000
7: 0.437500
8: 0.500000
9: 0.562500
10: 0.625000
11: 0.687500
12: 0.750000
13: 0.812500
14: 0.875000
15: 0.937500
16: 1.000000
17: 1.062500
18: 1.125000
19: 1.187500
20: 1.250000
21: 1.312500
22: 1.375000
23: 1.437500
24: 1.500000
25: 1.562500
26: 1.625000
27: 1.687500
28: 1.750000
29: 1.812500
30: 1.875000
31: 1.937500
```

### loadfloat.c

```c
/* Read floats from a binary file & dump to stdout */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "test.data"
#define DATALEN 32

int main(void)
{
    FILE *infile;
    double data[DATALEN];
    int i, n;

    if(!(infile = fopen(FILENAME, "rb")))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    n = fread(data, sizeof(double), DATALEN, infile);
    fclose(infile);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%d: %f\n", i, data[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The above C code produces identical output to that shown for `savefloat.py`.

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to implement this function in C++. But as you showed the C is easier.

Comment: @user1877600: No worries. I'm sure it's simple to read float data in C++ too, if you _really_ need that, but I never learned C++. The Python code could be made faster by writing the data in chunks (of say 64 kB) but that's probably not necessary, since modern OSes are pretty efficient at buffering disk operations.

Comment: @user1877600: I've just modified the C code to make it a little more robust.

Comment: A C++ solution to this is almost identical to the C one, there is a method [`istream::read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) that is very similar to `fread`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, the compiler crashes on such big data arrays.

What you can do besides of reading a binary file (since you don't want to do that) is to link with an assembly file. It still makes the executable self-sufficient and GAS is much more tolerant to big files. Here's an example of some asm file I generated using python and which assembles fine with classical `gcc`:

```
.section .rodata
.globl FT
.globl FT_end
FT:
.byte  0x46,0x54,0x5f,0x43,0x46,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x3,0x43,0x4f,0x4d,0x50
.byte  0x32,0x30,0x31,0x0,0x3,0x88,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0
.byte  0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0
.byte  0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x28,0xe6,0x47,0x6,0x7,0x8,0x28,0x28
.byte  0x26,0x6,0x2a,0x6,0x6,0x40,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0
FT_end:
```

That technique allowed me to embed a 80 Megabyte binary file (1 million code lines) in an executable because I had no filesystem to read data files in that environment (QEMU)

Real test with the python code I finally could dig out:

Python code:

```
floats = [0.12,0.45,0.34,4.567,22.7]

import struct
contents = struct.pack('f'*len(floats), *floats)

outbase = "_extref"
output_file = "data.s"

fw = open(output_file,"w")
fw.write(""".section .rodata
.globl {0}
.globl {0}_end
{0}:
""".format(outbase,outbase))
eof = False
current_offset = 0

while not eof:
    to_write = []
    if current_offset==len(contents):
        break
    if current_offset<len(contents):
        fw.write(".byte  ")
        for i in range(0,16):
            if current_offset<len(contents):
                to_write.append(hex(ord(contents[current_offset])))
                current_offset+=1
            else:
                eof = True
                break
        if len(to_write)>0:
            fw.write(",".join(to_write)+"\n")

fw.write(outbase+"_end:\n")
fw.close()
```

`test.cpp`: C++ code (C++11, I struggled for the pointer references to the asm part):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <strings.h>

extern const float extref;
extern const float extref_end;

int main()
{
    int size = (&extref_end - &extref);
    std::cout << "nb_elements: " << size << std::endl;
    std::vector<float> v(size);
    memcpy(&v[0],&extref,sizeof(float)*size);

    for (auto it : v)
    {
      std::cout << it << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Python code generates a `data.s` file. Create an executable with:

```
g++ -std=c++11  test.cpp data.s
```

run:

```
nb_elements: 5
0.12
0.45
0.34
4.567
22.7
```

The main advantage of this method is that you can define as many symbols as you want, with the format that you want.